# collapsing counted elements in a list into one

Tags: python, list

```
def change_greedy(amount, coinage):
    """greedy change"""
    change = []
    coins = coinage.sort(reverse = True)
    count = 0
    
    for coin in coinage:
        while amount:
            if coin <= amount:
                count += 1
                change.append((count, coin))
                amount -= coin
            else:
                break
        count = 0
    return change
    

print(change_greedy(82, [1, 10, 25, 5]))
```

This is the output I should get: `[(3, 25), (1, 5), (2, 1)]` and this is what I am getting now `[(25, 1), (25, 2), (25, 3), (5, 1), (1, 1), (1, 2)]`

How can I count it in a way that it doesn't count like 25,1 25,2 25,3 and just does 25,3?

Comment: Only append, if needed, before `break`ing?

Comment: I suggest using integer division within the if condition, to find out exactly how oft you want to use a given coin

Answer (score 0):

```
def change_greedy(amount, coinage):
    """greedy change"""
    change = []
    coins = coinage.sort(reverse = True)
    count = 0
    
    for coin in coinage:
        while amount:
            if coin <= amount:
                count = amount // coin
                change.append((count, coin))
                amount -= count * coin
            else:
                break
        count = 0
    return change
    
    
    
    
    
print(change_greedy(82, [1, 10, 25, 5]))
```